# Limit number of objects of a self reference model with Prefetch Django

Tags: django, django-models, limit, self-reference, prefetch

I have 2 models: Post and Comment. Like this:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField()

class Comment(models.Model)
    content = models.TextField()
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post_parent = models.ForeignKey(
        Post,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=False,
        db_column='post_parent',
        related_name='comments',
    )
    comment_ref = models.ForeignKey(
        'self',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True,
        related_name='children_comment'
    )
```

Suppose that comments can have sub-comments in 1 level. With a post's ID, I want to get 5 newest comments (not sub-comment), each of them is prefetched with their 3 newest sub-comments.
My current implementation after searching is:

```
sub_comments = Comment.objects.filter(
                  comment_ref=OuterRef('pk'),
                  post_parent=post_id
               ).order_by('-timestamp').values_list('id', flat=True)[:3]
queryset = Comment.objects.filter(
               comment_ref=None,post_parent=post_id
           ).select_related('owner').prefetch_related(
                    Prefetch('children_comment', queryset=Comment.objects.filter(
                    id__in=Subquery(sub_comments)
                ), to_attr="cmt"))
```

That does not work. It doesn't limit the number of prefetched sub-comments. Please help me :D

Comment: As @dean commented, I forgot the timestamp field in the models.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a date field on the `Comment` table so you can show the latest comments and sub comments.

I would introduce another model here so its easier for queries and writing tests personally for me.
Models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField()


class Comment(models.Model)
    content = models.TextField()
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post_parent = models.ForeignKey(
        Post,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=False,
        db_column='post_parent',
        related_name='comments',
    )
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField()


class ChildComment(models.Model):
    parent_comment = models.ForeignKey(
        Comment,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True,
        related_name="child_comments"
    )
```

Views.py

```
post = Post.objects.get(id=<some_id>)
comments = Comment.objects.filter(
    post_parent_id=post.id
).prefetch_related(
    'child_comments'
).order_by(
    '-date_posted'
)[:5]

recent_comments = {}
for comment in comments:
    recent_comments[comment] = [
        comment.child_comments.all().order_by(
            '-parent_comment__date_posted'
        )[:3]
    ]
```

Pass `recent_comments` to the template `context` and then in a template file use it like:

```
{% for recent_comment, child_comments in recent_comments.items %}
    {{ recent_comment.content }}
    {% for child_comment in child_comments  %}
        {{ child_comment.content }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks for help Dean, but that's not what I want.
First, I want to use only 1 table for comment.
Second, what I asked is to limit the objects of Prefetch, not use a loop after that. It seems to have poor performance I think. 
I have found this https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/26780#comment:6. But it doesn't work in my case with self-ref table. In case separating comments into 2 tables, I think this is better, too

Comment: I've added a new answer, in terms of performance, you are only receiving 5 parent comments max, each with a max of 3 child comments, so the performance is going to be fast. Catching any obvious performance issues, I would say with the small amount of rows being returned, I would focus on readability more here than performance.

Comment: yes, I think so. But I think we're looking for solutions, not a workaround. Thanks ^^

Answer (score 0):

You will need a `DateTimeField` to get the latest comments and child comments in an `order_by`, but this query should work. This may not be ideal if you were returning thousands of comments, but only 5 at a time, this will be fast.

```
comments = Comment.objects.filter(
    post_parent_id=post.id
)[:5]
root_comment_ids = [comment.id for comment in comments]

child_comments = Comment.objects.filter(
    comment_ref_id__in=root_comment_ids
)[:3]
```